# Database Connectivity Issue

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm installing an application and getting following error:

> Can't connect to SQL Server DB.
>   Error: The TCP/IP connection to the host , port 1433 has failed.
>   Error: : Connection timed out. Verify the connection properties.
>   Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connection at the port.
>   Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.

Can someone please advise me?

Comment: this sounds like it belongs on [su]

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved with the help of SQL Server configuration Manager